# [Flask][Ajax] How to send and get multiple checkbox values

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to submit multiple checkbox values using AJAX and then add checked items to div element. Because a number of checkbox varies depending on cases, I don't know a way to send and get such a multiple data. In HTML code below, the length of the list `person_name` changes depending on users.

HTML:

```
 {% for name in person_names %}
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="{{name}}">{{name}}</label>
 {% endfor %}
 <a href=# id="add">Add</a>                                        

 <div id="names">
      Your checked names are: 
      {% for ckname in cknames%}
      <p>{{ckname}}</p>
      {%endfor%}
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a#add').bind('click',function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "/regist",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    data: { /* I can't find a way */},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (data) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    document.getElementById('names').appendChild(div);
    } 
});
})
```

Python:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
     return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/regist")
def register():
    cknames = request.form.getlist('check')
    return cknames %??
```

In addition I don't want to redirect the page, want to just add div element. Appreciate any helps!

Comment: Just captures all the looping checkboxes with an array so you can easily process it.

Comment: Thanks to quick comment @MuthulakshmiM. I'm unfamiliar with flask and javascript. Could you teach me more details?

Comment: Push values inside array and don't forget to send csrf token as well .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('[name=check]').serialize()` to get the data but your request is wrong.
Data received from `form.getlist` needs to be sent via POST and in form-data format.

```
$('a#add').bind('click',function(){    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/regist",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('[name=check]').serialize(),
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            document.getElementById('names').appendChild(div);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    });    
})
```

Comment: Thank you for great idea, @Musa. However, I still get stuck... I first rewrote to `ck=request.get_json()` and `cknames=ck['check']` as you mention but any response don't appear. What are my mistakes??

Comment: Did `request.form.getlist('check')` not work?

Comment: OMG, I misunderstood your comment... `request.form.getlist('check')` works well and what I want is obtained. Thank you so much @Musa!!